# Aurelia check clientWidth in attached event

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to find the appropriate event in the aurelia life cycle to check elements absolute width (to know if they are too narrow to insert text in them).
I thought that the attached event is the right one (where the model is attached to the DOM), but then I get that the elements width is 1:

```
<template>

  <div ref="notCompliantDiv" css="width:${displayData.notCompliant}%;">${notCompliantText}</div>
</template>

attached() {    
if (this.notCompliantDiv.clientWidth < 10) 
  {
    this.notCompliantText = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the HTML has attached itself to the page, but the element you're querying has a `css` attribute on it which is initialised by Aurelia itself. You're going to want to use the `TaskQueue` for this one.

The task queue will push the execution of your code to the bottom of the stack and run after Aurelia has done any of its dynamic logic over custom attributes and whatnot.

```
import { inject, TaskQueue } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(TaskQueue)
export class MyClass {
    constructor(taskQueue) {
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
    }

    attached() {
        this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() => {
            if (this.notCompliantDiv.clientWidth < 10) {
                this.notCompliantText = '';
            }
        });
    }
}
```